# Unable to connect to azure VM instance after service restart

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, restart

I am unable to connect to Azure VM instance of my service via Remote Desktop (connect option in the website). I am noticing this only after service restarts.
    Any idea about this issue? And how to fix it\workaround it?